# iOS app not opening a tel: link in a browser

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have this code and it's not working. Basically I want the iOS app to open the link containing a `tel:` URL in a browser.

```
extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        if let contains = webView.url?.path.contains("/nfc-activate"), contains {
            let tagId = webView.url?.lastPathComponent
            let message = NFCNDEFMessage(records: [NFCNDEFPayload.wellKnownTypeURIPayload(string: "https://app.domain.com/nfc/\(tagId?.description ?? "")")!])
            NFCSessionManager.shared.write(tagId: tagId?.description ?? "", message: message, sendTo: self)
        } else if let contains = webView.url?.path.contains("/scan"), contains {
            //scan qr
            addQrPreview()
        }
        
        else if let urlString = webView.url?.absoluteString.lowercased(), (urlString.contains("wa.me") || urlString.contains("vcardsave") || urlString.contains("mailto")) {
            if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
                let httpURLString = "https://\(url)"
                if let httpURL = URL(string: httpURLString) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(httpURL)
                }
            }
        }
        
        else if let urlString = webView.url?.absoluteString.lowercased(), urlString.contains(":tel") {
            if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url)
            }
        }


        
        
        else if let contains = webView.url?.path.contains("/account"), contains {
            let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginViewController") as? LoginViewController
            vc?.communication = self
            self.present(vc!, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried multiple ways to do it but I keep getting the same issue. It does not respond on a click to a tel, email, or vcard link.

Simply open the link containing tel in Safari.

Comment: `UIApplication.shared.open(url)` with a `tel:` URL will launch the Phone app. Why would you want such a URL to open in a web browser? What do you want the web browser to do with such a URL?

Comment: Why are you checking for `:tel` and not `tel:`?

Comment: Checking for tel:, the issue is i am using webView in Xcode wnd for the tel link the APP simply does not respond, so i want it to open the dialer.

Comment: @Paulw11 actually i found 1 mistake after your referral, let me try that. :)